# What should I do if I want to inject non-static inner classes in Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, redis

Spring declares a non-static inner class, USES an external class as a constructor parameter, and error message as follows:
no matching constructor found in class 'Keys'
Validate Constructor Arg Injection
Thank you in advance

```
public class JedisUtil {
public Keys KEYS;
public JedisPool jedisPool;

/*************************Keys******************************/
public class Keys {
    public String flushAll() {
        ***
    }  
}
```

Configuration in Spring-Redis：

```
<bean id="jedisKeys" class="com.imooc.o2o.cache.JedisUtil$Keys" scope="singleton">
    <constructor-arg ref="jedisUtil"/> 
</bean>
```

Comment: You should usually start by using Spring Boot, which would make this entirely unnecessary (it will handle Redis connection setup for you).

Comment: Thank you very much, but I am still a novice

Comment: Go to https://start.spring.io/. In "dependencies", select "Spring Data Redis (Access+Driver)" (as well as any other dependencies you need). Provide `spring.redis.url` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#data-properties), and everything is ready to work. You can inject `RedisOperations` interface to get operations such as `flush` already defined.